# Mobile input fields aren't working on a mobile but work on a tablet

Tags: android, css, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have created a form for PC and tablet/mobile with my site. The form works well on a desktop and a tablet but on a mobile when I click on the field, it is briefly highlight blue as it should when selected on an android device. But it never brings up the keyboard to type in the box. Whereas on my tablet it works every time. 
*I am using a samsung galaxy tab2 (tablet) and sony expiro mini (phone).*
The only thing I can think of is my phone may not be too slow to run the site through [Adobe Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/?kw=semgeneric&sdid=KAPIO&skwcid=AL!3085!3!26964251330!b!!g!!adobe%20edge%20inspect&ef_id=UaUGogAAAEVIXPoS:20131121140630%3as). 
If that is the reason should I just overlook the functionally on my phone and use it to check how the design looks?

Here's part the code, in-case its relevent:

HTML

```
<p><select id="prefix" class="form_fields"  name="prefix"   onBlur="get_name(this,'1')">
 <option>Title</option>
 <option>Mr</option>
 <option>Mrs</option>
 <option>Miss</option>
 <option>Ms</option>
 </select><br/>
 <input type="text" id="f_name" class="form_fields"  placeholder="First Name" maxlength="150" onBlur="get_name(this,'2')" /><br/>
 <input type="text" id="l_name" class="form_fields" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="150"  onBlur="get_name(this,'3')" /></p> 
<div id="nameError" style="position:relative; width:70%;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.form_fields{
    font-family:continuum_lightregular;
    width:60%;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:8px;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:18px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding:top:5px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: why are you wrapping form elements in `p` tag?

Comment: No real reason, just a habbit for splitting things up.

Answer (score 1):

Check the software version of your phone and tablet. Old apps may be a problem.

Comment: That could be it, I installed chrome on my phone and it works perfectly. The default android browser seems to have quite a few that don't work properly on it. Ill give updating the default browser a shot.